# WebRTC what is the correct way to removeStream and addStream again

Tags: webrtc

My RTC session was started with text only. And video is added by user when needed (renegotiation)

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function (myStream) {
    localVideo[0].srcObject = myStream;
    myConn.addStream(myStream);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

When user do not need the video session anymore, I remove using:

```
var tracks = localVideo[0].srcObject.getTracks();
tracks.forEach(function (t) {
    t.stop();
});
myConn.removeStream(localVideo[0].srcObject);
localVideo[0].srcObject = null;
```

Everything is working fine, until I try to add the video again I noticed that the `createOffer()` request size is getting larger and larger.

Seems to me that WebRTC didn't **forget** about the previous stream, and is adding to the offer again and again. Or maybe my way of removing a video stream / track is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue see [this thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webrtc/2019Feb/0036.html) on the W3C list.

The best way to get around this is to use `replaceTrack` and is suggested in the thread.

```
Note: It is still possible to prevent the list of transceivers from growing
by *manually* recycling them using transceiver.sender.replaceTrack() and
transceiver.direction, but that still wastes resources on transceivers
currently not used, and implies you probably shouldn't use
transceiver.stop() in most cases.
```

Also see the ["Unified Plan" Transition Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-ZfikoUtoJa9k-GZG1daN0BU3IjIanQ_JSscHxQesvU/edit#heading=h.jokxmhjugemd)